# iOS Access Extension target bundle ID from main target

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier, cfbundleidentifier

I have main target and extension target, each one has bundle id. I want to access extension target's bundle id from main target, runtime. Is it possible to do it?

I did not find solution in internet.
I appreciate if you can provide some info about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "access"?  You can work it out at runtime, since the extension's bundle id is the containing app's bundle id plus whatever additional suffix you have used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.